# Not able to access Javascript variable which is in Scope..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-5

Below is my javascript code.. I am declaring the variable 'allproductsAndPrice' outside the function.. But I am not able to access it after i initialize it.! Am i doing something wrong?
when I try to alert it, It doesn't print anything.

```
var allproductsAndPrice = "";
$.getJSON("/Home/GetProducts",
    function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            allproductsAndPrice = allproductsAndPrice + 
                "<option name='productName' id=" + data[i].productPrice + ">" + 
                data[i].Pname + "</option>";
        }
    }
);

alert(allproductsAndPrice);
```

Comment: You *are* doing something wrong... forgetting what the "A" in "Ajax" stands for.

Comment: @DaveNewton I dint get u.

Comment: Now  i got it!! poor logical thinking :( :(

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong here is that the alert will be called before the `getJSON`'s callback will be called. Which means that `allProductsAndPrice` is always an empty string in the alert.

The call to `getJSON` is asynchronous which means that it will trigger a "complete" event on the ajax request and then the callback will get executed. You could make the call to getJSON synchronous but that is kind of against the idea.

To get a better idea of what is happening right now is this:

1. Initialize `allproductsAndPrice` to "" on the current scope.
2. Create an Ajax request
3. Alert with the content of `allproductsAndPrice` which is still ""
4. Complete event is triggered
5. Execute callback and affect something to `allproductsAndPrice`

What you should do instead is this:

```
    var allproductsAndPrice = "";
    $.getJSON("/Home/GetProducts",
      function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
              allproductsAndPrice = allproductsAndPrice + "<option name='productName' id=" + data[i].productPrice + ">" + data[i].Pname + "</option>";
          }

          // More code that should be executed
          alert(allproductsAndPrice);
    });
```

Comment: but i am initializing 'allproductsAndPrice' inside the $.getJSON function right? So it wont update??

Comment: @Uthaiah no you're not.

Answer (score 0):

try this. This will work and help you in identifying if there is an error.
And second thing var **allproductsAndPrice** will remain empty in alert because ajax request is async, javascript will not wait for ajax response.

```
var allproductsAndPrice = "";
try {
    $.getJSON("/Home/GetProducts", function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            allproductsAndPrice = allproductsAndPrice + "<option name='productName' id=" + data[i].productPrice + ">" + data[i].Pname + "</option>";
        }
    });
} catch (e) {
    alert(e.message);
}
alert(allproductsAndPrice);
```